# log4cxx DOMConfigurator prints configuration information to the console

Tags: log4cxx

I'm working on a large project that uses several modules and plugins.  We use log4cxx for logging in all of these modules and plugins.

Each time log4cxx::xml::DOMConfigurator::configure("xml_config_file") is called, the configuration information is displayed to the console:

```
log4cxx: Threshold = "".
log4cxx: Level value for root is [trace]
log4cxx: OptionConverter::toLevel: no class name specified, level=[trace]
log4cxx: root level set to TRACE
log4cxx: Retrieving an instance of Logger.
etc...
```

While this may be helpful during debugging... it isn't helpful to our testers.  It causes too much output.

I do not have a Console Appender configured... The output is sent to a log file.

How can I turn this off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, finally found the correct verbiage to find an existing answer (not on this site).

Basically at the top of the configuration file you'll see:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
```

It's the debug="true" that was causing it to print to the console.  I set it to false and it doesn't do it anymore.

Best,
Ace